# Need to Strip URL of everything except Node Number

Tags: xml, drupal

I have a large xml file (>30mb) that has paths such as yoursite.com/category/section/3389121/title-article

I need to strip everything except the node number in the path.  I thought maybe using Regex, but not sure how to make it not apply to the rest of the xml fields.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's SimpleXML library to parse out just the XML fields you need, and then run your regex against them. Once you see the syntax it uses to do this, you'll understand why it's called SimpleXML.

Comment: Thx Forest, I think I can make that work.  I'd offer an 'up' arrow, but it won't let me.

Comment: You now have up-arrow ability.  ;-)